# mismatched input 'from'. Expecting: ',', <expression>

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto

I have a query that I am running on AWS athena that should return all the filenames that are not contained in the second table. I am basically trying to find all the filename that are not in ejpos landing table.

The one table looks like this (item sales):

| origin_file | run_id |
| --- | --- |
| /datarite/ejpos/8023/20220706/filename1 | 8035 |
| /datarite/ejpos/8023/20220706/filename2 | 8035 |
| /datarite/ejpos/8023/20220706/filename3 | 8035 |

The other table looks like this (ejpos_files_landing):

filename

filename1

filename2

filename3

filename4

They don't have the same number of rows, hence I am trying to find the file names that are in ejpos_pos_landing but not in item sales table.

I get this error when I run:

```
mismatched input 'from'. Expecting: ',', <expression>
```

The query is here:

```
SELECT trim("/datarite/ejpos/8023/20220706/" from "validated"."datarite_ejpos_itemsale" where 
run_id = '8035') as origin_file, 
FROM "validated"."datarite_ejpos_itemsale"  
LEFT JOIN "landing"."ejpos_landing_files"  ON "landing"."ejpos_landing_files".filename = 
"validated"."datarite_ejpos_itemsale".origin_file
 WHERE "landing"."ejpos_landing_files".filename IS NULL;
```

The expected result would be:

|filename4|

Because it is not in the other table

Can anyone assist?

Comment: You don't need the comma after `as origin_file` before `FROM` in your `SELECT`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your assistance, I removed the comma but I am getting the same error.

Comment: `trim("/datarite/ejpos/8023/20220706/" from "validated"."datarite_ejpos_itemsale" where 
run_id = '8035') as origin_file` - what are you trying to achieve here? This is not a valid sql.

Comment: If you check the table, I have an entry like this: /datarite/ejpos/8023/20220706/filename1 I want to extract filename1 from /datarite/ejpos/8023/20220706/filename1 where run_id equals 8035, then I want to use those results to do the difference checks.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of wrong stuff in your query based on the example data and declared goals.

- `trim("/datarite/ejpos/8023/20220706/" from "validated"."datarite_ejpos_itemsale" where  run_id = '8035') as origin_file` is not a valid sql.
- `ON "landing"."ejpos_landing_files".filename =  "validated"."datarite_ejpos_itemsale".origin_file` will not work cause origin_file is prefixed. You can use [`strpos`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/string.html#strpos) if there should be only one instance of `filename` in the `origin_file`.
- your join and filtering condition are build to find items present in `datarite_ejpos_itemsale` and missing in `ejpos_landing_files` while you state the vise versa is needed.
- the mentioned in the comments extra comma

Try next:

```sql
-- sample data
WITH item_sales(origin_file, run_id) AS (
    VALUES ('/datarite/ejpos/8023/20220706/filename1', 8035),
        ('/datarite/ejpos/8023/20220706/filename2', 8035),
        ('/datarite/ejpos/8023/20220706/filename3', 8035),
        ('/datarite/ejpos/8023/20220706/filename4', 8036)
),
ejpos_files_landing(filename) as(
    VALUES ('filename1'),
        ('filename2'),
        ('filename3'),
        ('filename4')
)

-- query
select filename
from ejpos_files_landing l
left outer join item_sales s -- reverse the join
    on strpos(s.origin_file, l.filename) >= 1 -- assuming that filename should be present only one time in the string
       and s.run_id = 8035 -- if you need to filter out run id
where s.origin_file is null
```

Output:

| filename |
| --- |
| filename4 |

Alternative approach you can try:

```sql
-- query
select filename
from ejpos_files_landing l
where filename not in (
    select element_at(split(origin_file, '/'), -1) -- split by '/' and get last
    from item_sales 
    where run_id = 8035
)
```

Comment: Thanks but I am running this against a massive table so I am getting Query Timeouts

Comment: @user3476582 see the update with alternative approach.